# How to install Microsoft Virtual PC in win 10?

Tags: windows-10-upgrade, microsoft-virtual-pc

I just update Win 7 to Win 10, But Virtual PC 2007 doesn't work. I got Sp1 but it doesn't work. I'd be happy if you could help me.

Comment: It can't be done; Use Hyper-V if your using Windows 10 Professional or VMWare/VirtualBox

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but you can't use MS Virtual PC on Windows 10 (or Windows 8.x for that matter). You'll have to use Hyper-V, or some other virtualization tool like VMware or VirtualBox.